# Lua os.excute() function doesn't work properly

Tags: docker, shell, nginx, lua

I am Using a docker Image that runs **Nginx with Lua** extensions.

Whenever there is a request to path http://..../payload, I trigger a lua script that should execute a command from inside the docker.

This is my .lua script:

```
local method = ngx.var.request_method
if method == "POST" then
   os.execute("/etc/nginx/shellScript.sh")
end
```

shellScript.sh just creates a new file inside a given path:

```
touch /etc/nginx/testFile.txt
```

I see that all POST requests work, but the os.execute() doesn't do anything. When I check the path:

```
ls -la /etc/nginx/
```

the file testFile.txt is not created.

Only when I run ./shellScript.sh manually from the docker, I can see the new file created...

Please advice, Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it should work?  How the print method will solve the issue?

Comment: To where it should print the output in my case?

Comment: what makes you think that os.execute does not work properly? what does os.execute return?

Comment: @Piglet As I describes in the question, I expect it to open the file and run the .sh script. Then I will see a new file named "testFile.txt" under /etc/nginx/. Which I don't see now.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.execute, returns `true` when it works, so is it returning `true` or `nil`?

Comment: Which of the following is your exact problem: 1) The lua script is not invoked when POST request arrives; 2) Variable `method ~= "POST"`; 3) `os.execute()` tries but fails to run the script

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I edited my code to check what you say: ngx.print(os.execute()) and it returns "1". Not sure what it says. But my goal is not achieved yet. I don't see the file created in the docker itself.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff My problem is that I don't know if os.execute() works, and I don't see that result that I expect to see from it.

Comment: perhaps try `os.execute("/etc/nginx/shellScript.sh /etc/nginx/luaScript.log")` and see if the log file gets created, hopefully can gain some insight from the log if it is created

Comment: Could also be a permission issue.

Comment: `ngx.print(os.execute()) and it returns "1"` - This means shell has returned exit code 1.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff When I do ngx.print(os.execute("/etc/nginx/shellScript.sh")) I get 32256. This means nothing to me.. I still don't achieve my goal. The sh script is not executed and there is no new file named testFile.txt created.

Comment: `ngx.print(os.execute("/etc/nginx/shellScript.sh")) I get 32256` - It is `126*256`, and exit code 126 means "Permission denied"

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yup that's exactly what i though. Thus I changed the .sh script to chmod 777. Now I get 32512 which also belong to permissions, or not found. But the path I supplied is 100% corrent.

Comment: Probably the current user (behalf of whom shell file is being run) is unable to create files inside `/etc/nginx/`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I think the user is root.. how can I check who is the user that is trying to run this sh script? os who is the user that lua script is running from?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Also /etc and /nginx folder now have 777 permissions. But still receive 32512.

Comment: Return code 127 means the program was not found in the PATH.  It seems that you have to specify full path `/usr/bin/touch`

Comment: Can you please take a look on this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409811/lua-run-a-shell-command-with-parameters-doesnt-work

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff really need you help there.