# lua run a shell command with parameters doesn't work

Tags: python, shell, lua

I am trying to execute a command from lua script. The command is to simply run a python script named "sha_compare.py" of which receives 3 arguments where two of them are variables from the lua script - dady_data and sha:

```
local method = ngx.var.request_method
local headers = ngx.req.get_headers()

if method == "POST" then
   ngx.req.read_body()
   local body_data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
   local sha = headers['X-Hub-Signature-256']
   ngx.print(os.execute("python3 sha_compare.py"..sha..body_data))
else
```

The script fails because of the way I call the arguments. The actual command if I would have ran it from cmd would have been something like:

```
python3 python3 sha_compare.py sha256=ffs8df aaaaa
```

Please tell me how should I change my code to call the python script with 3 vars properly.

If it is not possible or hard to implement, please let me know how can I call a .sh script which will receive those 3 params.

Comment: What's inside `body_data`?  Does it contain characters which are "magical" for shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not providing spaces between the arguments: you're trying to execute

```
python3 sha_compare.pysha256=ffs8dfaaaaa
```

Do this:

```lua
os.execute("python3 sha_compare.py "..sha.." "..body_data)
```

It's often easier to build the command up as a table, and the concat it for execution:

```lua
local cmd = { 'python3', 'sha_compare.py', sha, body_data }
os.execute(table.concat(cmd, " "))
```

Comment: os.execute("python3 sha_compare.py "..sha.." "..body_data) doesn't work, won't even compile. I get error server 500. And the table option returns 512...

Comment: I added a full path to the script name. Now getting error 256.

Comment: Does body_data contains spaces and/or quotes? If so you'll have to make sure the value is properly quoted for the shell.

Comment: Can you please take a look over this thread as well? This is critical for me. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66527896/lua-script-does-not-close-nginx-although-ngx-close-defined